# put output from command into many variables in sh

Tags: bash, posix, sh

I have command, which output two columns. For example:

```
undefine@uml:~$ uptime -s
2015-10-26 08:47:12
```

How can i put this two columns into separate variables?
I would like to do something like:

```
undefine@uml:~$ uptime -s | read day hour
undefine@uml:~$ echo $day
undefine@aml:~$
```

I know, that in bash i can execute it like:

```
undefine@uml:~$ read day hour <<< $(uptime -s)
undefine@uml:~$ echo $day
2015-10-26
```

I can also redirect output from uptime to file, and then read from that file:

```
undefine@uml:~$ uptime -s > tmpfile
undefine@uml:~$ read day hour < tmpfile
undefine@uml:~$ echo $day
2015-10-26
```

But how to do it "posix sh way", and without creating any temporary files?

Comment: how about a temporary variable?

Comment: I found this `read a b c < <(echo 1 2 3)` in another thread. Is this POSIX compliant?

Comment: @tripleeee Your chosen duplicate was for `bash`, not POSIX.

Comment: @RamboRamon No, process substitution is not POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @chepner Thx, is there a nice source to look up such things?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: what temporary variable? can you explain?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I mostly just check the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) on a feature-by-feature basis as needed, and have absorbed the differences over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In POSIX shell, you can a here document along with command substitution:

```
read day hour <<EOF
$(uptime -s)
EOF
```

(Technically, this may still use a temporary file, but the shell manages it for you.)

Comment: What is your problem with your own second example?

Comment: If it has to be one line, use the temporary file and join the commands with `;`: `uptime -s > tmpfile; read day hour < tmpfile; rm tmpfile`. POSIX doesn't provide a one-line method of defining here documents; that's why `bash` and other shells provide here strings.

Comment: @RamboRamon `<<<` isn't part of the POSIX standard.

Comment: Which uptime actually takes arguments anyway? I've never seen it before so pretty sure most posix systems will not have it by default as well.

Comment: @123 That's not really relevant to the question or this answer, which provides a POSIX-compliant way of piping output from one command to a `read` command executed in the current shell. (`uptime` itself is not covered by the POSIX specification, so there's no telling what any particular implementation will accept.)

Comment: @chepner It's atleast vaguely relevant, as i would assume they want it posixly so that it is portable, but okay.

Comment: uptime was only simple example ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the two assigned variables being named `$1` and `$2`, you could use:

```
set $(uptime -s)
```

(This is not a completely serious answer.)

Comment: This is good; it overwrites the current positional parameters, but it's usually obvious when the current values need to be preserved and easy to actually do so.

Answer (score -1):

You could split it by piping to cut like so

```
myVar1=$(echo uptime -s | cut -d" " -f1)
myVar2=$(echo uptime -s | cut -d" " -f2)
```

This normally works for bash.  On sh you would have to use back ticks so

```
myVar1=`uptime -s | cut -d" " -f1`
myVar2=`uptime -s | cut -d" " -f2`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hm? It put ino myvar text "uptime -s" - not date/time :-)